# Units of measurement for different feature selection techniques

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to use multiple methods to select the best features, more especifically, ANOVA, Mutual information selection, Chi-2 and the internal feature selection method of Random Forest. I came across this [article on how to use selection feature techniques](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/) and the references inside to the sklearn api. However, I haven't found information on the units of these methods.
[image: Feature selection methods without units]

As you can see in the figure attached, they are significantly different and it would be nice to have each technique properly measured. Would anyone be able to share with me the units or a source where I can find them?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: In practice, I don't think I've ever needed the unit on these types of measures, as they're generally used for relative ranking of features within a particular dataset. I'm not sure you could meaningfully combine metrics from different tests on the same dataset, or compare even the same metric across different datasets, if that's what you're after.

Comment: I agree completely with you. My situation now is that I need this to publish a paper. However, the idea of ranking them instead of showing their score might do the trick. Interesting to see the diverging visions between climatic physics with machine learning (I was surprised to not see any reference to dimensional units in the sklearn library).